# Как установить слушатель движения по горизонтали в PhotoView?

Tags: java, android

У компонента PhotoView есть Listener на касание и двойное касание.

А нужно узнать "не было касания с удержанием по горизонтали", как бы "листания" влево, вправо, так чтобы это не перекрыло первых двух (касание и двойное касание).